# "He was made to feel guilty."

Tags: sentence-construction

> He was made to feel guilty.

or

> He is made to be felt guilty.

What is the difference between these two sentences. I'b appreciated if someone could explain me how to use "made to be..." phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase *make somebody feel guilty* can indeed be put in the passive:

> He was made to feel guilty.

But it's only the matrix verb (*make*) that can be made passive. The embedded verb *feel [guilty]* is intransitive (in this sense), and so does not have a passive: *be felt guilty* is not grammatical.